# why the function “strlen” can't get the length of "ch1" modified like this?

Tags: c++, string

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wxebf.jpg)

I declared a pointer that pointed to an type of char array, and I changed one of the elements to '\0'. I think the function "strlen" can get the length for the first elements to the '\0' , but actually, the program crashed. Anybody knows the reason ?

Comment: Don't link to screen shots, post code.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the actual code *as text*.

Answer (score 0):

Your character pointer points to a string literal, which is immutable data. For backwards compatibility reasons, the compiler allows a non-const `char*` to point to the literal, but as you noticed, attempting to modify the string crashed the program.